# IOrchardHost.GetShellContext - Creating and setting up tenants

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to create and setup tenants by code.
When I write this code:

```
_tenantService.CreateTenant(tenantSettings);
var shellContext = _orchardHost.GetShellContext(newTenantShellSettings);
```

shellContext is null. Then I changed the code to this:

```
_tenantService.CreateTenant(tenantSettings);
_orchardHost.EndRequest();
_orchardHost.BeginRequest();
var shellContext = _orchardHost.GetShellContext(newTenantShellSettings);
```

This time, shellContext is valid but it invalidates the login state (I mean log out me).

What's wrong all with this?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/dev/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.MultiTenancy/Controllers/AdminController.cs
It doesn't attempt to use the tenant right away. Instead, it redirects. The tenant activation or de-activation happens on a different action. I think it's because there's a lot of things that need to happen when a new tenant is added, that can't happen all on the same request.

Comment: Thanks @BertrandLeRoy, I will try to split the procedure into two actions with redirecting.